# Find specific argument and pass it to command

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I have a script called **test_script** that needs to run a file called **run_command** as follows:

```
./run_command <input path>
```

If I supply the script with the following arguments:

```
./test_script argument1=sometext argument2=othertext inputpath=/folder1/folder2/file.txt argument4=moretext
```

How can I make the script find the argument **inputpath=/folder1/folder2/file.txt** and pass **/folder1/folder2/file.txt** to **run_command**? Keep in mind that inputpath=/folder1/folder2/file.txt won't necessarily always be in third place and the amount of arguments supplied may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
inputpath=(${${(M)argv:#inputpath=*}#*=})
(($#inputpath > 0)) && ./run-command $inputpath
```

Would extract all the *path*s in `inputpath=path` arguments to the script and store the non-empty ones in the `$inputpath` array. Then we run `./run-command` with those inputpath as arguments if any were found.

POSIXly, you could do something like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
run_with_extracted_keyword() (
  cmd="${1?}" keyword="${2?}"
  shift 2
  for arg do
    case $arg in
      ("$keyword="*) set -- "$@" "${arg#*=}"
    esac
    shift
  done
  [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && exec "$cmd" "$@"
)

run_with_extracted_keyword ./run-command inputpath "$@"
```

GNUly, you could do:

```
#! /bin/bash -
set -o pipefail
printf '%s\0' "$@" |
  LC_ALL=C grep -zPo '^inputpath=\K(?s:.*)' |
  xargs -r0 ./run-command
```

Comment: If the inputpath argument had newline(s) then the grep will give incorrect results. Y? For the . in .* will not match a newline.

Comment: @RakeshSharma, good catch, thanks. Fixed now.

Comment: In the `case`-based solution, y r u assuming that the keyword might come multiple times? Also the case select section can be improved by `("$keyword="?*)`

Comment: Thanks, your zsh suggestion worked nicely!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, if you control the input, and can restrict the script access to prevent shell injection as stated by Stéphane in comments:

```
#!/bin/bash
  
for arg; do
    declare "$arg"
done

echo "$argument1"
```

```
sometext
```

Usually, to access positional parameters, you can do `echo $1`, `$2`, `$3`...

But if you use this `var=value` form, this code will fit better

Comment: That would introduce a command injection vulnerability though as data passed in the arguments could be interpreted as shell code.